# How to get current img src by jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on wordpress's widget now I've to need make a option for upload image. But no image link (src) added on my input field.

This is my Jquery:

```
 window.send_to_editor = function(html){
        var imglink = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        jQuery('.img1').val(imglink);
        tb_remove();
    }
```

But when I used this code, without html

```
window.send_to_editor = function(){
        var imglink = jQuery('img').attr('src');
        jQuery('.img1').val(imglink);
        tb_remove();
    }
```

Then I got this src link

```
http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/9269ac5e9e06aa762e2c5a497007806f?s=26&d=mm&r=g
```

But I want to get current img link which I insert in my widget.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
$(this).attr("src", urlAbsolute);
```

[Demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ekeru4/19/edit?html,js,output)